# How to import @react-pdf/renderer on Docker?

Tags: reactjs, docker, pdf, react-pdf

I got the below error.

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-pdf/renderer' in '/app/src

I can run with 'npm start', but I cannot run with 'docker-compose up'.
I noticed that I cannot use models that contain '@'. Do you know how to resolve this problem?

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app
# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_PATH /app/node_modules:/app/src:$NODE_PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN yarn install

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```